# Микропроцессор К580ИК80

Tags: ассемблер

Объясните, что такое `Jmp m, Сlr А, Мov А,D, Аdi В1`.  А лучше скиньте ссылки на литературу, где можно о них почитать.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `jmp m` - переход (jump - прыжок) на указанную метку
- `clr A` - возможно очистка (clear) регистра `A` (не нашел такой инструкции для i8080)
- `mov A,D` - (move - двигать) копировать значение из регистра `D` в регистр `A`
- `adi B1` - (возможно add immediate) увеличить аккумулятор (регистр `A`) на число (непосредственное значение) `B1`

Краткий справочник по процессору i8080 и аналогичных ему процессоров серии K580:
[Микропроцессор 8080](https://web.archive.org/web/20121127002141/http://www.computer-museum.ru/technlgy/i8080.php)